# How to view these no file extension files exist in the android>data>xyz app>files folder?

Tags: applications, apk, files, pdf, data

I have installed an app from play store, which contains pdf files. When I click on download button the app download them in such way that these files are only able to be opened in that app. (Like how youtube saved videos offline)

I cannot share these files to my PC. When I went to Android/Data/XYZAPP/Files, I get to see these files. But I cannot open them directly. They have no file extension (e.g. 234828173)

I tried to open them with bin file viewer. They contains a lot of binary or hex code.

Those are the pdf files (because if I download 2 pdf there shows 2 files if I download +1 there gets a +1 file, except them there are no files in that specific app data folder), how can I open them like I open other normal pdf files.

Thanks

Comment: Ask the developer of the app what obfuscation or encryption they are using on the saved files.

Comment: The files can be obfuscated, encrypted, compressed and so on. Unless it is a very common file format (e.g. identifiable using Linux `file` command) you can only get the file format by decrypting and interpreting the decompiled code.